# Python: Why call '__init__' instead of className()?

Tags: python, constructor, initialization

Since calling `className()` will execute the code in `__init__(args)`, why in the code below, is someone explicitly calling `__init__`?

```
class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
```

Is there any difference in the actual code that is executed between the two method calls, or is chossing `__init__()` over `className()` simply arbitrary?

Running Python 3.4

Answer (score 9):

`className()` does more than call `__init__`.  It also calls `__new__`, which creates a new instance of the class.  So calling `Frame()` would not do the superclass initialization on the same `self` object; it would create a new object and initialize that.

You call `__init__` when you want to run *just* `__init__` on a particular instance you've already created.  Typically this is in a situation like the one you show, where you want to let a superclass do its initialization on top of a subclass's initialization.

Comment: so calling Frame's `__init__` is like calling `super()` in java?

Comment: @joshsvoss: Possibly.  I don't really know Java.  My experience with answering questions on this site is that people usually wind up with a better understanding if they try to understand what Python actually does instead of mapping it onto Java.

Comment: You can also use `super(Frame, self).__init__(parent)`, but I confess that I don't completely understand the difference in this context.

Comment: @daniel: Yeah, that's sort of a separate issue though.  Basically the `super` way  is more flexible in case you later rearrange the class hierarchy.